# Can I update a file in SharePoint without losing the lock

Tags: c#, sharepoint, locking

I'm currently working on a research project and I need to develop a locking scheme for a concurrent system. Now, I want to update the contents of a file without losing the lock, so that the user can continue editing the file.

There are two functions which might me applicable in this situation:

[SPFile.CheckIn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467428)
[SPFile.Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.update)

But, does someone know what those functions do? I think I need the Update function, but the documentation does not explain if the file remains locked after the update process. Anyone who has got experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! While Update() only updates, Checkin() will only do the checkin. Be careful: Not every list in SharePoint requires a checkin.